# multi header to as a column pandas python

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pivot

I have dataframe in form:

```
   name a    a    b    b
0  NaN  00   01   00   01
1  aaa  xxx  xxx  xxx  xxx
2  aa1  xxx  xxx  xxx  xxx
```

I wish it in form:

```
    n   n  n   n    n    n
1  aaa  a  00  xxx  xxx  xxx
1  aaa  a  01  xxx  xxx  xxx
2  aa1  b  00  xxx  xxx  xxx
2  aa1  b  01  xxx  xxx  xxx
```

Comment: What is code for create `DataFrame` ? It is create from `file` ?

Comment: why would you get three columns with 'xxx'? it should become only one